# Error while trying to create react native project

Tags: react-native

I'm currently trying to create my first ever react native project, following the environment setup directions on https://reactnative.dev. I followed every step of the quickstart guide. The error appears when I try to do the step "creating a new application", with the command npx react-native@latest init MyProject, at which point I get the following error message:

error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
at createFromTemplate (/Users/myname/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:131:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/myname/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:184:3)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/myname/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)

I'm not sure what to do next. I ran npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli before trying to initialize my project, if that matters.

I'm using: yarn = 3.5.0, cocoa pod = 1.12.1, node = 18.15.0, ruby = 2.6.10p210

Comment: Can you add your cocoapods version, yarn version, node version, ruby version in your questions?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Did you complete the steps in the quickstart guide? Edit the question and show what you did to set it up.

Comment: @GuyIncognito yes, like I said in my post, I followed the directions on the quickstart guide. Edited it to reiterate and add more detail :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is the following:

1. Create a `react-native.config.js` file in the root directory of your project, and add this:

```js
   module.exports = {
     project: {
       ios: {
         sourceDir: './ios',
       },
     },
   };
```

2. In the terminal, run: `cd ios`, then run `pod install` to install all the necessary dependencies.
3. After that, `cd ..` to navigate to the root of the project, then run `yarn start` and `yarn ios` to run the project.